# python сохранить табличные данные в виде картинки

Tags: python, django, telebot

Есть необходимость из данных сделать таблицу и опубликовать ее в телеграмм (использую `telebot`). 
Как сделать?

Думал сделать *Excel* из данных, сохранить его, потом конвертировать его в картинку с помощью

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

а потом эту картинку посылать в сообщении, но как то сложно получается, может есть вариант попроще?

И, у меня этот проект в *Django*, может можно в нем сгенерировать *html* и вместо отображения сохранить ее в картинку?

Данные:

```
res = {'cb1': {'avgprice': 326.85, 'weight': 0.0980392249446845, 'lastprice': 321.15, 'income': -1.743919229004144}, 'cb2': {'avgprice': 27.375, 'weight': 0.07299310651776685, 'lastprice': 28.427, 'income': 3.8429223744292225}, 'money': {'avgprice': 0.0, 'weight': 0.8289676685375487, 'lastprice': 0, 'income': 0}}
```

пример картинки для выгрузки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите что у вас за данные и какую таблицу вы хотите получить.

Comment: в вашем проекте можно использовать Google Таблицы?

Comment: Доброе утро @Violet  , Google Таблицы не использую. А это как то может помочь?
Сейчас реализовал, через создание таблицы через openpyxl и потом с помощью ImageGrab конвертирую в картинку, после чего посылаю картинку с помощью telebot

Comment: https://github.com/violet1one/gs-to-jpg-send-tlgrm